# Why does float types works well with Keil but not with Eclipse (gcc)

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, floating-point, keil

As said in the title I am facing quite curious (maybe not so) behavior. While my program works fine when compiled with Keil, float variables behave strangely when the same code is compiled with gcc.

In my code, I printf the float variables : When compiled with Keil, it gives me the right values (i.e : `float value = 0.15` but with gcc, the `printf` returns blank stuff like : `float value =`)

Does anyone encountered the issue? Is it a matter of type definition? Compiler options?

EDIT: as P__J__ said : -u_printf_float is needed. This solved the issue, thank you

Comment: Without some code, who knows? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Why don't you show us your program?

Comment: @user253751 - because program does not matter this time. It is implementation specific question and you know the answer or not (ie. you have experience using those toolchains). General C deliberations are not relevant here

Comment: @P__J__ Of course the program matters. We need to know how you are printing the number. For example maybe you are printing the number with `char buf[12]; sprintf(buf, "float value = %f", 0.15); puts(buf);` which is a buffer overrun.

Comment: @user253751 no, using arm gcc or avr gcc nothing will happen as not chars will be assigned. By default all float formats are ignored. So no buffer overflow, as no buffer writes

Comment: @P__J__ But without knowing the platform and the code, we can't know that. You are guessing.

Comment: @user253751 do you know what `keil` is? If yes you know that it is uC project. 8051, or ARM. The erst is obvious. As I wrote if you do not know - you will not get any knowledge from the program

Comment: @P__J__ Some programs run on multiple platforms. It could run on ARM uC and also ARM PC.

Comment: @user253751 no floats in printf + keil & gcc shows with 99% probability the problem. Very common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is very easy. The printf float support has to be manually enabled in most implementations as it is memory consuming.

`-lc -lrdimon -u _printf_float`

Comment: Correct! This is the answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @Ben34 so upvote and choose the answer as correct - this the way you say "thank you" here