# Sending float voltage value via USB CDC

Tags: arm, stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I want to send the float type voltage value that I read with stm32f429I discovery card using adc reference voltage via usb cdc. My problem is this; I read the adc reference voltage and voltage value, and I can assign it to a float type variable. But when I want to send this variable via usb, the voltage value is read infinitely and I cannot send it. Can you help with this problem? The codes I use are below;

```
void Read_ADC()
{
 if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000000) == HAL_OK)
 {
  adc_value[count] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
  count++;
  if(count == 2)
      count = 0;
  Vdda = (float) 3.3 * (*VREFIN_CAL) / adc_value[1];
  Vadc = Vdda * adc_value[0] / 4095;
 }
}
```

I am trying to assign the char type of float adc value that is read as follows in the main part and I try to send it from USB.

```
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
while (1)
{
  Read_ADC();
  sprintf(volt_array, "%.4f", Vadc);
  CDC_Transmit_HS(volt_array, strlen(volt_array));
  HAL_Delay(100);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: float sprintf on a microcontroller? why not just send the value and do that on the other end?

Comment: maybe to display on serial console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does float types works well with Keil but not with Eclipse (gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726038/why-does-float-types-works-well-with-keil-but-not-with-eclipse-gcc)

Comment: here is the dupe with my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726038/why-does-float-types-works-well-with-keil-but-not-with-eclipse-gcc/60726341#60726341